# Which Android IPC model to choose

Tags: android, ipc, distributed-system

I'm building a system (for Android devices) which will have the following structure:

- 4 independent software components communicate with physical world sensors
- 1 independent "central" software serves as an algorithm coordinator mechanism for the aforementioned components. This means that this piece of software will need to communicate with the above. This will initially be a template so that many "coordinators" would be developed in the future exploiting in various ways the 4 components.

As all of the above have to be distributed and independent, all must be 5 different APKs. To make it clearer, the main coordination software must have access to the methods provided by each one of the 4 others and also receive feedback from them (no values needed; maybe custom events that a requested process has finished?).

Firstly, how would you propose implementing the 4 components? My best idea so far is to develop them as Android Services as no GUI is needed for them.

And what are your suggestions for the ideal communication mechanism between the 4 components and the central? I'm considering AIDL as an option but are there other possible?

Comment: you can consider broadcast receivers as well for communication between apps. I think you will also like to make these communications secure using id of the caller. some more details like type of data, frequency of updates whether it will be static or be fetched on demand will help visualizing a solution better.

Comment: Thank you for your time commenting on my question. I haven't thought of broadcast receivers at all. I will need to check them out for sure! My use case scenario so far will rely on this: the main app asks one of the 4 other apps to execute one of its methods (e.g. turn on the x LED) as well as receive events from it (e.g. app notifies the main app that the x LED was successfully turned on).